# how to fix this highlighter?

Tags: javascript, css

Why is my highlighter so buggy? To start, select the text and then choose one of the colors to make the selection bold. But, sometimes it doesn't do it and sometimes it does. Also, I only want that text to be bold not every instance of that same phrase. For example, if you highlight *Hello* all the Hellos will be bold. I only want the Hello selected to be bolded. **How do I fix this problem?**

```js
 $("#actual_verse").mouseup(function() {
    var text = "";
    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    
    if (/\S/.test(text)) {
      new_text = "<div id='color_div'>"+text+"</div>";
      
          $(".boxes").click(function() {
  var title = $(this).attr("title");
  var reg = new RegExp(text,"g");
   $('#actual_verse').html($('#actual_verse').html().replace(reg,'<strong>'+text+'</strong>'));
  document.getElementById('tooltip').style.display = 'none';
});
  
        
   // Tool Tip
  
var ele = document.getElementById('tooltip');
var sel = window.getSelection();
var rel1= document.createRange();
rel1.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal1'));
var rel2= document.createRange();
rel2.selectNode(document.getElementById('cal2'));
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
    if (!sel.isCollapsed) {
        debugger;
        var r = sel.getRangeAt(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb1 = rel1.getBoundingClientRect();
        var rb2 = rel2.getBoundingClientRect();
        ele.style.top = (r.bottom - rb2.top)*100/(rb1.top-rb2.top) + 'px'; //this will place ele below the selection
        ele.style.left = (r.left - rb2.left)*100/(rb1.left-rb2.left) + 'px'; //this will align the right edges together

        //code to set content

        ele.style.display = 'block';
    }
});

  // End of Tool Tip
  
  }
  
    
  });
```

```css
/* Tool Kit */

#tooltip {
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
    border:grey solid 1px;
    background: #373737;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
#cal1{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:100px;
    left:100px;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}
#cal2{
    position:absolute;
    height:0px;
    width:0px;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    overflow:none;
    z-index:-100;
}

.boxes {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 2px;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
}

#blue_box {
  background: #AAF6FF;
}

#green_box {
  background: #D6FFAA;
}

#orange_box {
  background: #FFBF98;
}

#purple_box {
  background: #D7D5FC;
}

#red_box {
  background: #FF9B9F;
}

#yellow_box {
  background: #FFF8AA;
}


/* End of Tool Kit */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id='actual_verse'> Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here Hello There Good Day Sam Was Here </span>
<div id='cal1'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='cal2'>&nbsp;</div>
<div id='tooltip'> <div id='blue_box' class='boxes' title='Blue'></div> <div id='green_box' class='boxes' title='Green'></div> <div id='orange_box' class='boxes' title='Orange'></div> <div id='purple_box' class='boxes' title='Purple'></div> <div id='red_box' class='boxes' title='Red'></div> </div> <br> <br>
```

Comment: Why the hank are you trying to reinvent the wheel and ask questions about this over and over again?

Comment: @dude I've sometimes had questions where I only get answers the second time I ask...

Comment: @dude Can you provide an example of mark.js?

Comment: Just have a look at the [website](https://markjs.io/) there is an example section